# Excel how do I make COLUMN() function return column from named range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am referencing values in a 7x7 `RANDARRAY()` that starts at I2 using an Index formula to populate values in a Table range in I12:P19. The formula that I have works but in order to port it to different tables throughout the workbook, I tried using the `ROW()` and `COLUMN()` functions thinking that it would reference the row and column of the table range and the `INDEX()` would return the corresponding value from the array.

The issue is that if the table range is I12:P19 the `ROW()` and `COLUMN()` functions think that I am at Row 12 and Column 8 which quickly put my values outside of the 7x7 RANDARRAY()

Here's a screenshot of the tables:
[image]

The first column in the bottom table should return 38 which references value 38 in another table (and returns a State name) but when I use `Evaluate Formula` the formula indicates that I am already in the 9th column which is outside of the 7x7 array and so I get an error ("FREE" is the placeholder text for an `IFERROR()` function that surrounds the formula).

The question then is: how do I, or can I, use `COLUMN()` and `ROW()` to reference the column and rows of the table range itself?

The formula, that works, as shown in column [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqmEo.png) of the range, is: `=INDEX(tblStateCap,RANK.AVG(INDEX(I2#,[@blank],thisTable[[#Headers],[1]]),I2#,0),2)`
I am trying to replace `[@blank]` with `ROW(thisTable[@blank])` and `thisTable[[#Headers],[1]]` with `COLUMN(thisTable[[#Headers],[1]])`

I'm also open to easier ways of doing this.

Note: the values showing a State name use the old formula and is correct for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly then the current outcome you are getting is reading from cell reference and not from the table.

However, the required outcome is as per below picture i.e. you want top left cell in table to be shown as Row 1 and Column 1 irrespective of its position in the sheet where first digit shows row position and second shows column position.

[image]

Simple way of doing this in the top left cell for ROW use

`=ROWS($A$1:$A1)`

and for columns use

`=COLUMNS($A$1:A$1)`

These will get updated in the table as you copy down and across. It will not be affected if you copy/move the table anywhere in the sheet.

Comment: so if I use `=ROWS($J$13:$J$13)` then that would reset the value of 1,1 to my starting point? 
Also, can I do that using named references like `thisTable[@ThisRow]`

Comment: I think I get the concept, but it's not working quite right.  I"m duplicating your table above as a proof-of-concept but all of the columns end up with the same value.  Here's my formula `=ROWS($S$25:T25)&", "&COLUMNS($S$25:T25)`

Comment: @Sam use the exact formula in the top left cell of the table and check the results.